# Html builder in .net 1.1?

Tags: .net, html

I'm currently doing some maintenance on some existing .net 1.1 VB code that creates `HTML` from code.
It mainly consists of a bunch of `stringbuilder.Append("<table>")`.

Isn't there a clean way to create HTML tags?

Answer (score 1):

[HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) should be in .NET 1.1. I thank that is the cleanest way using only .NET 1.1 types.